# what would be the most pythonic way of finding items from a list of OrderedDict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of ordered dicts that display information about courses
It looks like this:

```
[
...
OrderedDict([('c_number', '506'), ('c_name', 'Learning and Cognition'), ('c_category', 'B'), ('c_credits', '4')]),
OrderedDict([('c_number', '504'), ('c_name', 'Research Design'), ('c_category', 'A'), ('c_credits', '4')]), 
OrderedDict([('c_number', '616'), ('c_name', 'Research Techniques for Non-Experimental Social Sciences'), ('c_category', 'A'), ('c_credits', '4')]),
...
]
```

1. I need to find a way to access all the column values, without iterating over the rows. Is there a way to do this without iterating over each row?
2. Is there any other data structure that I should be using to store all this data, which would make it easier to operate on?

I want to do the following operations:

- find if a particular course_number is in the list
- sum up the credits for a particular course category
- find if courses in list are sufficient to meet the pre-req

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome.

Comment: "I need to find a way to access all the column values, without iterating over the rows. Is there a way to do this without iterating over each row?" no, there isn't. You'd have to iterate over the ordered dictionaries in some way.

Comment: Not a list: a dictionary indexed by `c_number`?

Comment: Have you thought of using sqlite and making a database?

Comment: If you want to be able to do those operations without iterating over all courses, then you need a different data structure - end of story.

Comment: yes, this is why I wanted to know if there was a different data structure/approach. What about using a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the first step in creating a lightweight database for your data which is easily queried with SQL:

```
import sqlite3
DBNAME = "course_catalog.db"

def create_table():
    with sqlite3.connect(DBNAME) as conn:
        curs = conn.cursor()
        sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS courses
        (
            id integer primary key,
            c_number TEXT
            c_name TEXT
            c_category TEXT
            c_credits INTEGER
        )
        """
        curs.execute(sql)
```

See for example: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/creating-database/